# Javascript floating point changes accuracy depending on how you input the variables

Tags: javascript, floating-point, precision

**EDIT: This is not a discussion about how great or broken the floating-point implementation in JS is. This is a very specific case, so please do not mark this as a duplicate of a discussion about floating-point.**

This is the script I use to calculate the decimal portion of an amount expressed in cents (Ex. 3.34 is 334 cents):

```js
const amount = 334;
const decimal = Math.trunc(100 * ((amount / 100) % 1).toFixed(2));

console.log(decimal); //34
```

So far so good. If you change the amount to 329 you get 28, which is wrong:

```js
const amount = 329;
const decimal = Math.trunc(100 * ((amount / 100) % 1).toFixed(2));

console.log(decimal); //28
```

This is due to the fact that `(329/100) % 1 = 0.29000000000000004` instead of `0.30`, because JS floating-point sucks?

But what is really crazy to me is that while developing a loop to see the cases in which that script breaks using a FOR, it does not break on 329!:

```js
for(let x = 325; x < 335; x++) {
  
  const r = Math.trunc((100 * (( x / 100) % 1)).toFixed(2));
  console.log(x, r);

}
```

What am I missing here? Why is working when inside the loop and not working when calling the function directly? And how can you calculate this in a robust and reliable way?

Comment: It's not *JavaScript* floating point, it's *all* IEEE floating point implementations.

Comment: I don't know why the loop works correctly, but I would advise you to keep away from floating point when possible, wouldn't just `329 % 100` work for you ?

Comment: Use module 100, example: `334 % 100`

Comment: `100 * ((amount / 100) % 1).toFixed(2)` performs a different computation than `(100 * (( x / 100) % 1)).toFixed(2)`. Parentheses matter.

Comment: @EricPostpischil you got it, I did not saw those extra parentheses. Thanks!

Comment: @Barmar: This was a bug in the code, not a floating-point duplicate. Seeing there is some unexpected result and floating-point is in use is not a valid criterion for judging a question to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Analysing this:

```
const amount = 329;
const decimal = Math.trunc(100 * ((amount / 100) % 1).toFixed(2));
```

- `(((329/100) % 1).toFixed(2))` returns the **STRING** `"0.29"`
- If converting it back t a number, it is scanned to the nearest possible float 0.289999999999999980. You can proof it by: `(+(((329/100) % 1).toFixed(2))).toPrecision(18)`
- Then you multiply the result by 100 and truncate it, so you get the correct value 28.

Functions like `toFixed()` or `toPrecision()` are designed to format number for the final output, but not for mathematical calculations.

Solution for you problem:

```
const amount = 329;
const decimal = amount % 100;
```

... or if amount can be a float with fractions.

```
const decimal = math.round(amount) % 100;
```

**One last note:** This is a discussion about the implementation of floating-point and how to work with it; and not only for JS!